# Perl class attribute inheritance

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I have class attribute, e. g., counter of created objects in some base class,

```
package A;
our $counter = Counter->new; # not just a counter in fact, so initialization code should be inherited by descendants as well

sub new {
    $counter++;
    bless {}
}
sub get_counter {
    $counter
}

package B;
use base 'A';

package main;
B->get_counter();
```

I want package B to have his own copy of this class attribute (e. g., counting objects of B class only), and all inherited methods from package A should deal with this copy. What is the correct way to implement this in plain perl and in Moo/Moose? Seems like MooX::ClassAttribute can not be inherited.
One ugly solution found is to repeat attribute initialization code in each descendant and use symbolic dereference like ${"${class}::counter"} in ancestor's methods to access this attribute with actual package name. But seems like there should be more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Perl object model has no concept of class attributes. And there's no kind of hook like “when a new subclass is created, run this code”.

Instead, the base class could maintain a hash of counters, using the class name as keys:

```
package A;
my %counters;

sub new {
  my ($class) = @_;
  my $counter = $counters{$class} //= Counter->new;
  $counter++;
  return bless {} => $class;
}

sub get_counter {
  my ($self_or_class) = @_;
  my $class = (ref $self_or_class) || $self_or_class;
  $counters{$class};
}

package B;
use parent -norequire, 'A';
```

This will create a new counter when an instance of a subclass is created. Note that the first argument to a method is either the class name or the object instance. We need to use that in `new()` as the hash key. In `get_counter()` I've written this in a way that the method can be called on both a class and an object to the same effect.

A similar technique is known as inside-out objects, where store object fields in a hash held by the class, so that the object itself doesn't contain any data.

(Why `parent` instead of `base`? The `parent` module only does inheritance, whereas `base` also integrates with the `fields` pragma which you should not use.)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to implement this task in its original form using Metaclasses techniques in advanced object packages like Moose and its smaller clones?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with the Moose meta-object protocol (MOP). Moo does not have a MOP. I'm hoping someone else will contribute a Moose-based answer.